# Android 8.1 BLE scan not working

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-8.1-oreo

Whenever I turn off the screen of my pixel 2 with Android 8.1, the scanner is turned off as it is already described here:
[BLE scan is not working when screen is off on Android 8.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077690/ble-scan-is-not-working-when-screen-is-off-on-android-8-1-0)

I tried specific scan filter attributes and also an empty scanfilter with no success, the scanner is disabled and wakes up after switching the screen on.

> Logcat output (screen is turned off):
>
> Cannot start the unfiltered scan in screen-off. This scan will be resumed later...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your code? Apparently it thinks you perform an unfiltered scan.

Comment: Hi Emil, I simply add an empty scanFilter. `List<ScanFilter> filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(filters, settings, ScanCallback);` Below Android 8.1 everything was working fine so far.. Have you got any idea? Actually if there is a an empty filter defined it should match any advertising packet, and still allow detections with the screen off on Android 8.1.

Comment: An empty list means no scan filters. You need to have at least one scan filter. Can't you provide a scan filter. I assume you are trying to scan a device that advertises a specific service?

Comment: Yes I try to scan for specific advertisements packets (ibeacon format). This was my first approach:`ScanFilter.Builder builder = new ScanFilter.Builder();
builder.setManufacturerData(0x004c, new byte[] {});  ScanFilter filter = builder.build();` but still I don't get any scan results when I switch off my display and following output still appears: Cannot start the unfiltered scan in screen-off. This scan will be resumed later...

Comment: I tested on Pixel 2 and I was able to reproduce this bug, but I was not on Pixel 2 XL running the same OS version. Maybe it is related to the device...