# BLE scanning issue in Pixel2 Oreo version 8.1.0

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-8.1-oreo

I have made an android app which will scan all BLE device near by. It is working fine in All versions of Android(above kitkat) except Android 8.1.0 on pixel. When, I kill application it will continuous scanning but After pressing lock or power button it stopped scanning.

Comment: I got solution form here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077690/ble-scan-is-not-working-when-screen-is-off-on-android-8-1-0?rq=1