# How to Continuously scan for the ble devices using Ionic 4 and get the advertising data

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ionic4

what i am trying to do :   using https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central  plugin creating a android app using ionic and need to get the rssi data and advertising data also continuously even in screen lock also.

what i did :
            right now i am getting the data after pressing the scan button and rssi data and advertising data in buffer

what i need :

1. How to get/ scan the bluetooth devices continuously including their advertising data ?
2. How to scan even though the screen is locked or app is in background ?

below is my code:

html code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      BLE Scanner
    </ion-title>
    <ion-button (click)="Scan()" slot="end">
      <ion-icon name="Bluetooth"></ion-icon>
      <p>Scan</p>
    </ion-button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-card-content ion-item *ngFor="let device of devices">
      <p>{{device.name || 'Unnamed'}}</p>
      <p>{{device.id}}</p>
      <p> RSSI: {{device.rssi}}</p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

.ts code :

```
import { BLE } from '@ionic-native/ble/ngx';


  devices: any[] = [];

  constructor(private ble: BLE, private ngZone: NgZone) {

  }
  Scan() {
    this.devices = [];
    this.ble.scan([],5).subscribe(
      device => this.onDeviceDiscovered(device)
    );
  }
  onDeviceDiscovered(device) {
    console.log('Discovered' + JSON.stringify(device, null, 2));
    this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.devices.push(device)
      console.log(device)
      let  adData = new Uint8Array(device.advertising);
      console.log(adData);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**How to get/ scan the bluetooth devices continuously including their advertising data ?**

According to the plugin doc:

https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#scan

```
{
    "name": "TI SensorTag",
    "id": "BD922605-1B07-4D55-8D09-B66653E51BBA",
    "rssi": -79,
    "advertising": /* ArrayBuffer or map */
}
```

the plugin should provide you BLE device should provide advertisement either your decoding of buffer must be not right or else the device is not advertising the packets.

**How to scan even though the screen is locked or app is in background ?**

you can try this plugin for background mode scan

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Comment: with out background mode plugin will the ble central wil emit values in background ? if so up to how much time ?

Answer (score 1):

**How to scan even though the screen is locked or app is in background ?**

As suggested by Mohan Gopi a background-mode plugin could help, but it is not the whole solution starting from Android 8.1

[BLE scan is not working when screen is off on Android 8.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48077690/ble-scan-is-not-working-when-screen-is-off-on-android-8-1-0)

As you can read scan with a locked screen is allowed only with filters and cordova-plugin-ble-central doesn't allow to set an empty filter (at least I have not found it).

The solution is to set an empty filter, but I am still looging for a plugin that allows this.